# react-i18next function this.props.t('id', value)

Tags: react-native, localization, i18next, react-i18next

I am able to this.props.t('id') function which return string translation for given id.
Now, I have a requirement to get string translation for `"Change value for " + (this.state !== null ? this.state.selectedData.length : 0) + " selected data"`. 
In this translation, I'll have to use a variable inside string translation.
Is there any method such as : this.props.t('id', value)??

How can I get this working?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1):

Read docs, this called [interpolation](https://www.i18next.com/translation-function/interpolation), you can set in your translation value:

```
{
  ...
  "MY_KEY": "Change value for {{value}} selected data" 
  ..
}
```

And then call

```js
this.props.t('MY_KEY', { value: this.state !== null ? this.state.selectedData.length : 0 });
```